# Why I have multiple Python version installed on my Ubuntu 20.04 DEV machine?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to start a Python project on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine and I have the following doubt. It seems to me that I have multiple Python version installed on my machine.

Into the **/usr/lib/** directory I have the following subdirectories:

- python2.7/
- python3/
- python3.8/
- python3.9/

Ok the firest one referers to the old legacy Python 2 version but why I am finding 3 different Python 3 versions?

If I perform the command:

```
andrea@ubuntu:/usr/lib$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.5
```

I obtain that the used one related to the **python3** command is the 3.8.5

So I have the following doubts:

is it refered to my **python3/** folder or to my **python3.8/** folder? Where is defined the association of the **python3** command to the effective Python version used?

What can I do to have a clean situation where I only have the Python2.7 and one of these Python3 version?

Comment: Isn't this a better Question for Super User or Server Fault? And which one (I don't know).

Comment: `python3` might just be an soft link to either `python3.8` or `python3.9`. Do `ls -l /usr/lib` to check.

Comment: You can find what it is refering to by running `which python3` in bash.

Comment: @pciunkiewicz it says which python3
/usr/bin/python3

Comment: @AndreaNobili then it is referring to the python install in `/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @andrew it seems that python3 is a propper directory and not a link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you have different versions of python installed on your machine is because either other software you have installed on your machine depend on different version of python, or you've installed the different versions your self.

You can try to uninstall a specific version of python using your package manger, i.e. [apt remove](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html)

On Debian based systems (and Ubuntu is based on Debian) the [`update-alternatives`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html) command/system is used to determine the default version/application the system will use for various component. So for example you can use update-alternatives to set the default system editor and the default python version.